# Can Every Square Matrix be written as product of two commuting matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The title explains it all. Can every square matrix $A$ be written as $A=B_1B_2=B_2B_1$ of any two matrices $B_1$,$B_2$.

Comment: $B_1=A$ and $B_2=I$?

Comment: Or $B_1 = \lambda^{-1} A$ and $B_2 = \lambda I$ for some scalar $\lambda \neq 0$.

Comment: good one! but that is kind of trivial. If $A$ is diagonalizable, I could write $B_1=X\Lambda^{p} X^{-1}$ and $B_2=X\Lambda^{q} X^{-1}$ where $A=X\Lambda X$ and $p+q=1$. That is a bit non-trivial

Comment: Well, you did say "any two matrices". Do you want the $B_1$ and $B_2$ to have some particular property?

Comment: How about non-diagonal?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, you can write it as $A^{73}A^{-72}=A^{-72}A^{73}$.

Comment: Bring $A$ to Jordan normal form. If $A$ has k distinct eigenvalues or k Jordan blocks, you can write $A$ as a product of $k$ mutually commuting matrices, one for each eigenvalue/block. If $A$ has only 1 eigenvalue, then it is either proportional to the identify matrix or compose of a single Jordan block with off-diagonal elements. In the 1st case, write $A$ as a product of $B B^{-1}$ for an invertible matrix. If the second case, if the eigenvalue is not zero. you can take the formal square root of $A$. The remaining case can be done but this comment box is running out of characters...

Comment: $B_1=A\exp(A)$, $B_2=\exp(-A)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, and you can produce arbitrarily many such factorisations. Take any polynomial $P$ whose zeros are not eigenvalues of $A$, then $P(A)$ is invertible, so you can write $A=AP(A)\cdot P(A)^{-1}$. More generally, you can replace $P$ by an entire function (or power series that converges on a disk with radius bigger than the norm of $A$).

I think you have to add more details to your question, e.g. require $B_1$ and $B_2$ to satisfy some additional conditions.

Here's another question: Can you characterise all possible factorisations?

Comment: Since every square matrix satisfies a polynomial equation (Cayley-Hamilton gives you a concrete one), what is the point of using entire functions or power series? You get nothing more than with polynomials of degree up to $n$ (the size of the matrix).

Answer (score 2):

To answer a variant of the question in a comment by OP under the question: a diagonal matrix with distinct entries cannot be written as a product of two commuting *non-diagonal* matrices (in fact both commuting matrices need to be diagonal). If $A=BC=CB$ then $B$ commutes with $BC=A$ (similarly for $C$), and any matrix that commutes with $A$ must stabilise each of the eigenspaces of $A$; since here these are $1$-dimensional, this means $B$ and $C$ are diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix is low rank (rank(A) < n) you can factorize the matrix using row-reduced echelon form of A. That produce A = CR. But A is not equal RC. So low rank matrix A can't be written as A = B1B2 = B2B1